# Laravel: Have an existing query but need to apply it to only the last 30 days

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a query:

```
User::selectRaw('users.facebook_id')
                    ->join('orders', 'orders.customer_id', 'shop_users.id')
                    ->groupBy('shop_users.id')
                    ->havingRaw('SUM(orders.total) >= 0')
                    ->get()->pluck('facebook_id')->all();
```

but I want it only for `orders` from the last 30 days from now.
I assume I could use something such as `->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))` but not sure how to apply this to `orders`.

Comment: What do you mean? you want the query to stop working after the 30 days? then your start date is the created_at?

Comment: @Jovs no, to only apply to orders created in the last 30 days from now

Comment: What do you mean? you want to sort the created_at in the last 30 days??

Comment: or you mean that you want to get the orders in the last 30 days ?

Comment: Your question is confusing maybe you can give example of output that you want.

Comment: right now, i'm only checking `orders.total >= 0` and then plucking the `facebook_id` from those orders.   But in pseudocode, I want to apply the query to `orders.total >= 0 WHERE 'orders.created_at' < 30 days ago"

Comment: so you want where between day now to 30 days in the past?

Comment: @jova exactly! yes

Comment: Kindly see my answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think where between is what you need

**Here try this**

```
User::selectRaw('users.facebook_id')
                    ->join('orders', 'orders.customer_id', 'shop_users.id')
                    ->groupBy('shop_users.id')
                    ->havingRaw('SUM(orders.total) >= 0')
                    ->whereBetween('orders.created_at', [Carbon::now()->addDays(-30), Carbon::now()])
                    ->get()->pluck('facebook_id')->all();
```

This will work if your datatype is `dateTime`.

now if you want to date only you can use this `->toDateString()` just add this on your carbon

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Join function from Laravel Code base,

```
/**
 * Add a join clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $table
 * @param  \Closure|string  $first
 * @param  string|null  $operator
 * @param  string|null  $second
 * @param  string  $type
 * @param  bool    $where
 * @return $this
 */
public function join($table, $first, $operator = null, $second = null, $type = 'inner', $where = false)
{
    $join = $this->newJoinClause($this, $type, $table);

    // If the first "column" of the join is really a Closure instance the developer
    // is trying to build a join with a complex "on" clause containing more than
    // one condition, so we will add the join and call a Closure with the query.
    if ($first instanceof Closure) {
        call_user_func($first, $join);

        $this->joins[] = $join;

        $this->addBinding($join->getBindings(), 'join');
    }

    // If the column is simply a string, we can assume the join simply has a basic
    // "on" clause with a single condition. So we will just build the join with
    // this simple join clauses attached to it. There is not a join callback.
    else {
        $method = $where ? 'where' : 'on';

        $this->joins[] = $join->$method($first, $operator, $second);

        $this->addBinding($join->getBindings(), 'join');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

That means, you can do may be something like below

```
User::selectRaw('users.facebook_id')
                    ->join('orders',function ($j) {
                        // Now $j is instance of builder e.g.
                        // $j->on('users.id', '=', 'orders.id')->orOn('users.name', '=', 'orders.name')->->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(30));

                        // Not super clear on the tables you are using
                      })
                    ->groupBy('shop_users.id')
                    ->havingRaw('SUM(orders.total) >= 0')
                    ->get()->pluck('facebook_id')->all();
```